# “Firmware Upgrade encountered an issue. Please select recovery mode in Kies” on reboot randomly, but device still working fine

Tags: samsung-kies, reboot

My Galaxy Note 2 N7100 has “Firmware Upgrade encountered an issue. Please select recovery mode in Kies” shows up randomly on system reboot, recovery reboot (from reboot menu in Touchwiz based official firmware 4.3, 4.4.2 both stock kernels and custom kernels), but rarely. When it happens I just press volume up and power to do force reset, and it boots normally, never failed.

What is the cause of the problem? Is it a sign that flash memory is going to be dead soon, I use flash memory quite intensive, installed ROMs more than 10 times, stored a lot of data in userdata to almost full, cleared up some space, and stored new files.